# How to assign dynamic color to vertex?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am working on a simple OpenGL application, which uses the base of Triangle Tutorial. For fun, I decided to add a third value. The Data format is (*data*, *x_axis*, *y_axis*). *data* acts as a z-axis value, but the z-axis can be kept zero. However, I want to draw just the *data* at the point where x_axis and y_axis point in the 2D plane. for example, if (x,y) = (0.23, 0.2) and data value is 0.23, I want to place this data value to the marked (x,y). Moreover, the shaders which I have written (sort of basic), are not working properly, or I am missing something?

1. every x_axis and y_axis has data scanned in a range of angles. x_axis lies between 30-120, whereas the y_axis lies between 30-110.
2. using vec4 since I am considering 4 points, of which Z remains 0. Will remove Z-axis completely.
3. Can I draw the *data* separately, after the vertex are drawn?

vertex shader

```
#version 460 core

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 projection;
in vec4 pos;


out vec4 cvColor;

void main()
{

  
    if(pos.z <= 0.10)
    {
        cvColor = vec4(0.323, 0.242, 0.22, 1.0 );
    }
    else if (pos.z > 0.11 && pos.z <=0.20)
    {
        cvColor = vec4(0.322, 0.241, 0.3, 1.0);
    }
    else if (pos.z > 0.21 && pos.z <=0.30 )
    {
        cvColor = vec4(0.453, 0.245, 0.33, 1.0);
    }
    else
    {
        cvColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    }


    gl_Position = projection*model*vec4(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z, 1.0);
    
}
```

fragment shader

```
#version 460 core

uniform vec4 cvColor;
out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    color = cvColor;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `**in** vec4 cvColor` in the fragment shader?

Comment: Color problem fixed. other two please.

Comment: What do you mean by "other two"? If you want to just use x,y for drawing, then do that and use 0.0 instead of `pos.z` in the vertex shader.

Comment: Will do that. And how should I draw the data point exactly where the XY points in 2D plane?

Comment: Isn't that already happening when you ignore the z-axis for the position? The main problem is that the information in the question is not very consistent. If you have data like `(data, x_axis, y_axis)` then why is there a vec4 input in the shader? And how did the order change? Why is data on the z value if you initially had it on the x axis?

Comment: Added a few things. Please check. Thank you.